# Adding raster layer with RPC file in ArcGIS for Desktop for ortho rectification with DEM file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, dem, orthorectification

I have a Pleiades image with its RPC file with .xml extension and a DEM file of the same area, but when I import them the orthorectification button is not active in display tab of property window.

How can I add them?

Comment: Pleiades? you mean the open star cluster? and you want to combine it with a DEM, from where in earth? I'm just curious and surprised about your question.

Comment: @DelonixR. see [Pleiades-1A Satellite Images](http://www.satimagingcorp.com/gallery/pleiades-1/)

Comment: Thanks @Sarbarz, I've got an astronomical misunderstanding (glitch!)

Comment: How and where are you importing them?  What license level and extensions are you using?  As it stands I think your question may be too brief on details to attract a potential answerer.